# JS - Call function and receive new value from array each new call

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function and for it to return a new string each time it is called. If it is called and all strings have been called it then loops back to the start.

Pseudo Code:

```
function getString(){
    var array = ['1','2','3','4'];
    // JS Magic??
    return finalVal;
}
```

Expected Magic:

```
getSting();    
1
getSting();
2
getSting();
3
getSting();
4
getSting();
1
getSting();
2
```

You get the idea I'm sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use scope to persist current index. Something like this.

```
var getString = (function(arr, i) {
   return function(){
       return arr[(i++)%arr.length]
   }
}(['1','2','3','4'], 0))
```

```js
var getString = (function(arr, i) {
       return function(){
           return arr[(i++)%arr.length]
       }
    }(['1','2','3','4'], 0))
console.log(getString());
console.log(getString());
console.log(getString());
console.log(getString());
console.log(getString());
console.log(getString());
console.log(getString());
```